# calling VoiceListActivity of Voice Recorder

Tags: android, android-intent, samsung-mobile

I am trying to call VoiceListActivity of VoiceRecorder from my app on samsung S4 but I get following error

```
08-27 09:35:03.401: E/AndroidRuntime(17313): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.sec.android.app.voicerecorder/.VoiceListActivity } from ProcessRecord{449e11c8 17313:com.example.ui_sha/u0a205} (pid=17313, uid=10205) not exported from uid 10193
```

my code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_RUN);
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.sec.android.app.voicerecorder/com.sec.android.app.voicerecorder.VoiceListActivity"));
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

So my question is :

- Can i use Intent to call VoiceListActivity from my app? If yes, How I have to do ?
- If no, can you show me another way to call it ?

Solution :

I asked some body to solve this problem but it is impossible when code in VoiceList's manifest have android:exported = true. So the only solution is you need to build your own VoiceListActivity and its screen. It could be take some time but it is only solution.

Comment: Try to add : <activity android:exported="true" android:name="co   m.sec.android.app.voicerecorder.VoiceListActivity"/> in AndroidManifest.xml under <application> tag. and also replace this code : intent.setComponent(ComponentName("com.sec.android.app.voicerecorder","com.sec.android.app.voicerecorder.VoiceListActivity"));
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

Comment: Thanks for reply Haresh, but it is not working. it have the same error. im crazy now :(